# Locked out of my phone as the touchscreen isn't working

Tags: touchscreen, locked-out, broken-screen, media-files

I have a LG Optimus G. Some parts of the **touchscreen doesn't function**.

I wish to **retrieve the media content** from my phone. Nothing more. So, hard reset is not an option.
I can't use a mouse over OTG as Optimus G, "doesn't support it".

What are my options?

**USB debugging is on**, but is on Charging mode. Hence, my predicament.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery installed? If so you may be able to retrieve your files with adb.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab No, I do not.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for some first aid? If so, what have you tried? As your touch screen isn't working, our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) might prove helpful as well.

Comment: How did connecting phone to PC via USB work out?

Comment: @SaileshSriram is your device connected to the Internet with a Google account?

Comment: @AaronGillion It isn't. Anyway I can turn on the internet being locked-out?

Comment: @SarpSTA No help. It's on "Charging Mode".

Answer (score 0):

You say USB debugging is on. Is your phone is already "paired" with certain computers - that is, it it set to automatically allow USB debugging from certain computers? Usually the answer is yes for your personal computer(s).

Assuming this is the situation, you can easily ADB shell to tar/gz any folder(s) you want and "ADB pull" the tar/gz file to your computer.

Another option that you might want to explore is the [Vysor application](http://www.vysor.io) (currently for Chrome), that allows remote control via ADB.

Comment: Prior to Marshmallow, when the device was explicitly switched to charging mode in USB connection mode , USB debugging used to get disabled in the device. The option about USB debugging would show being enabled though.

Comment: Does Vysor connect with my phone automatically over USB?

Comment: It should, if USB debugging is enabled. If however USB debugging is disabled in charging mode as @Firelord suggests, then it wouldn't work.